# Mute Button C# Metro App

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and have almost created an Windows 8.1 Metro application, but I can't seem to find a way to make a button that mutes sound of the app.
I tried several ways to do this but nothing worked.
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps just use a button that sets each individual soundfile to 0 volume? I know I can set the volume of a wav file in WP8; haven't tried Windows 8.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. For Windows Phone, I can set the volume of a media element to 0 simply, like this:

mediaElementName.Volume = 0;

Comment: Yeah thanks this works if I have the media element in Blend, but if I created a media element with xaml on Visual Studio like this:
`MediaElement sound = new MediaElement();`
then for the effect to take place and have the volume to 0 I have to refresh the page.
I was hoping that there could be a way to make the whole app's Volume to 0 somehow...
But this was very helpful and if I don't receive any other answer the next 2-3 days I'll mark this as answered! ;)
Thanks again.

Comment: Well I haven't done anything outside of WindowsPhone and C#, but I'm not sure why you'd have to reset the page for the effect to take place. But I will try to find a solution. Sorry if I don't succeed!

Also, I don't know what your sound files are, but maybe just pause them? 'code'mediaElement.Pause();